# How to debug in .rs file with RenderScript?

Tags: android, debugging, renderscript

I want to add some log in fall.rs (in:packages\wallpapers\Basic\src\com\android\wallpaper\fall). And the code is like this:

int root(void) {

```
rsDebug("===========root==================",0);
rsgClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
...
```

}

But my device can't print any log when I set live wallpaper. Although there are many examples about "rsDebug", but I can't find what's wrong when I use "rsDebug".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of device is this (and what version of Android is it running)? Also, rsDebug logs at the "D" (Debug) level, so if you are filtering logcat, you might just not be seeing it. Do you see any messages tagged as "D"?

Comment: Hi, I test add some log in native function with "LOGE" and "LOGD". But only "LOGE" can print log. How can I modify the logcat output level? Maybe I must compile a debug ROM instead release ROM.

Comment: Can you try running with: adb logcat *:D

Comment: Is it possible to do real debugging of Renderscript ? I mean, with breakpoints and such ?

Comment: We are working on a real debugger (via lldb), but it isn't ready yet.

Comment: It has not shipped as part of the SDK/NDK yet.

Answer (score 1):

To see all renderscript debug messages from logcat, use:

```
adb logcat -s RenderScript:D
```

To filter for your specific application, add a prefix in the rsDebug message:

```
rsDebug("==MyApplication== my debug message", 0);
```

and filter in logcat:

```
adb logcat -s RenderScript:D | grep ==MyApplication==
```